# Auto publish and enable articles from registered users in Joomla 3.3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3

I want to let registered users to create/edit their own articles under only one menu of my website. It works well but I need to manually enable them.
How can I set **automatic publishing/enabling** without giving them publisher rights?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "under one menu"  but you can limit publishing rights for a group to a single category. Otherwise I would write a plugin to either automatically publish on save or to modify the form for htat group so that the form shows the state field.

Comment: I meant menu item. I set permissions for a group to a single category. I allowed create, edit state and edit own. But it still needs admin approval...

Comment: If edit state is allowed then admin approval should not be required. The problem is that joomla doesn't know what category will be set for a new item so it can't show the edit state field because it might be in error.   This is one of these weird logical problems.  So what you need to do is basically ensure that the create can only happen in the specified category and then force display of the state field. But make sure you do it right so they can't modify with Firebug.

Comment: Good. Could you write what steps should I do?

Comment: You should read the documentation on making a plugin, and try it. Once you post some code if I'm around I'll give you some feed back on it,  YOu might also  get some good advice on the Joomla stack exchange site.